# redirect all files with .php extension

Tags: apache, unix, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, webserver

have this code in a htaccess file to hide the final php extension of each file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

but now i want to redirect to another page if the user try to complete the extension.

i tried this line after the script above but i get a 500 internal error

```
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404]
```

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your rewrite rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} !^myvar=0
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php?myvar=0 [QSA,L]

# but don't allow example.com/foo.php
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} !^myvar=0$
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404,L]
```

Basically first rule is appending a dummy query parameter `myvar=0` in the URL and second is checking its non-presence to kick in, hence if user types /abc.php then it is blocked but if just /abc then it is internally redirected to /abc.php.

Comment: hi. have you tested the code? i just copy-paste but i get an internal error (500) thanks

Comment: @Fel: Yes I have tested that in my XAMPP apache and it was working. May I know on which platform are you testing it? I will test it on my Linux host as well and let you know.

Comment: @Fel: I have edited my answer, please try and let me know. I have tested it on my Ubuntu Apache installation and it is working fine.

Comment: i just changed the 404 to 301 and now works well. 
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=301,L] thanks!

Comment: @Fel: Since you wanted to block http requests if user types `.php` in the URL so 2nd rule is doing that. But you can of course alter your jquery code to `$(".button").click(function(){ $("#replace").load("index"); })` and it will work as before.

Answer (score 1):

Mod_rewrite only accepts the values 301, and 302 (the default if not specified) for the `R` flag.  If you wish to send to a 404, I'd recommend sending the request to a custom 404 page: `RewriteRule \.php$ /404.php [L]`, where 404.php sets the Response Status to 404.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Server Help Documentation:
Apache 2.2 was released in 2005 - 10 years ago.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server

Apache 2.2 R Flag HTTP response status code help info:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r

> Any valid HTTP response status code may be specified, using the syntax
>   [R=305], with a 302 status code being used by default if none is
>   specified. The status code specified need not necessarily be a
>   redirect (3xx) status code. However, if a status code is outside the
>   redirect range (300-399) then the substitution string is dropped
>   entirely, and rewriting is stopped as if the L were used.

Apache 2.4 R Flag HTTP response status code help info:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r

> Any valid HTTP response status code may be specified, using the syntax
>   [R=305], with a 302 status code being used by default if none is
>   specified. The status code specified need not necessarily be a
>   redirect (3xx) status code. However, if a status code is outside the
>   redirect range (300-399) then the substitution string is dropped
>   entirely, and rewriting is stopped as if the L were used.

Additional relevant Info:

"The target (or substitution string) in a RewriteRule is assumed to be
a file path, by default."

"- (dash)
A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a flag (see below) needs to be applied without changing the path."

In plain english the substitution string is the http URI path were you are rewriting/redirecting too. So that means that when you use a 4xx redirect range, such as R=405, then a URI target path will be ignored/not allowed/not used if one is present in the RewriteRule.

This RewriteRule is valid and works in most cases/most servers/server configuration, but may not work in every single case so yep if you want something that works in 100% of all server configurations then you would dumb this code down and not use R=405. In Live testing R=405 works in 99.99% of all cases on hosts worldwide.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=405,L]
```

Dumbed down code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path-to-405-error-logging-file/405.php [L]
```