# How do I allow .php, trailing slash, and no trailing slash? 

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

How do I allow .php, trailing slash, and no trailing slash?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)(\.php|\/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ %1 [R=301,L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
#directory ban
Options All -Indexes

ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php

FileETag MTime Size
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 86400 seconds"

# 1 WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
# 2 DAYS
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
# 1 MIN
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=60, private, proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# any Expires Directives go here
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# any Header directives go here
</IfModule>

<ifmodule mod_deflate.c="">
<filesmatch ".(js|css)$"="">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modified .htaccess file instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options All -Indexes

ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php    
## doesn't work for me
##FileETag MTime Size
##ExpiresActive on
##ExpiresDefault "access plus 86400 seconds"
# 1 WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
# 2 DAYS
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
# 1 MIN
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=60, private, proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c="">
<filesmatch ".(js|css)$"="">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</filesmatch>
</ifmodule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} !^myvar=0
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..*$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /$1.php?myvar=0 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Hm, now all my web pages besides my index.php won't work. At first, when I tried to go any non-index page, I got redirected to my domain.com/error with the error "This webpage has a redirect loop". Then, I removed my "errordocument /error.php" from .htaccess. Now I just get a broken link. I think redirecting might have some repercussive effect now. Is there any way I can just make all, .php, trailing slash, no trailing slash, all work?

Comment: Right now the best I got is "# BEGIN NoExtensions
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule (.*)/?$ $1.php
# END NoExtensions". Trailing slash doesn't work with this...

Comment: As per your question you are trying to make `/foo.php OR /foo/ to /foo` Is this correct?

Comment: Yes I want to make it so it doesn't matter whether the person enters /foo, /foo/, or /foo.php . All would lead the person to the same page.

Comment: Above rule is actually already doing that (I have tested as well). However when final URI becomes /foo it will get 404 unless it knows somehow that you are actually serving /foo.php for URI /foo. I would request you to see my answer today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544919/redirect-all-files-with-php-extension which is probably doing what you want.

Comment: I tried the code and replaced the 404 with 301 as suggested. Both allows domain.com/page.php, but not domain.com/page/ nor doman.com/page

Comment: I have tested and edited my answer for your requirements, please try them and let me know.

Comment: Hmmm, it doesn't work :/. I posted my entire htaccess up. Maybe something is disrupting it?

Comment: @user657847: please see your edited .htaccess file above in my answer.

Comment: Trailing slash and .php works. No trailing slash doesn't. :-/

Comment: @user657847: I had actually tested all 3 conditions before posting and all 3 worked fine in my xampp apache installation. If you notice I have `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$` in the rule which makes slash `/` optional because of `?` and hence that also works. Try clearing your browser cache and restarting your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try below rules to make it work according to your requirement,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)(\.php|\/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Let me know in case it doesnt work..

Comment: Hm, same problem I experienced with anubhava's code. I actually want .php, /, and no slash to work now (no redirects). Can you tell me how that's possible? For more information, look at my response to anubhava hah

Comment: Above rules is working exactly what you mentioned in your question i.e.,
`/foo.php --> /foo`
and
`/foo --> /foo`
I tried into my local domain too.. and its working...

Comment: Hmmm, it doesn't work :/. I posted my entire htaccess up. Maybe something is disrupting it?

Comment: Replace your last too line with
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`
If still doesnt work... let me the error which you are getting...

Comment: Now, when I go to domain.com/subsection.php, domain.com/subsection, and domain.com/subsection/, I get redirected to /error with an error "This webpage has a redirect loop" on Chrome.

Comment: try hit that url again `domain.com/subsection/` it will redirect to `domain.com/subsection` for me also it was giving /error but when i tried again... it is working... :)

Comment: I tried anub's code and it worked after I cleared my cache. I'm sure it would have worked on your code too. Thanks for the help man! +1